# i have only put 1600 hundred miles on car sense last oil change, company said i need to change every 6 month regardless of miles are they correct,?

Tags: honda

I have put 1600 miles on car sense last oil change. Company said i needed to change oil every 6months regardless of miles are they correct? Or just looking for the money for oil change.

Comment: The answer is in the owner's manual for the car. However it also depends on whether they filled it with the correct grade and type of oil, or "garbage that looks vaguely like oil," at the previous change.

Comment: Or you could take the word of an anonymous person on the internet instead of the designer and builder - owners manual.

Comment: Could you post the make, model and year of vehicle please?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does the vehicle have an oil life monitor?

Answer (score 2):

Low mileage implies the car is not driven for long periods . Short drives do not thoroughly heat the oil to drive out water ( from combustion), this is the most severe service for motor oil. So, for example, if a car is driven for 10 minutes twice a day ,the oil never gets hot and should be changed more often the the average requirement in the owners manual. On the otherhand , one drive of a hundred miles once a week is very easy service as the oil is well heated. Many of the additives in motor oil are there to compensate for the corrosive affects of water. Ironically , taxi cab service where the engine is hot from almost running nonstop is the mildest service for oil. Amoco ran Super Permalube motor oil in taxi cabs in the '70s for 50.000 miles with only additions for loss. A standard motor oil , not synthetic. The objective was to compare it to Mobile One , the first common synthetic which was giving strong competition. I am sure the data was not published; the SPE Journal may have a paper with no brand names. By the way the cab engines did fine with no oil changes, they are hot so long there is no moisture condensation.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree with the "need to" part of this.

You can use a car during its entire lifetime without ever changing the oil.  The problem is that the lifetime can be shortened from this.

You **should**, however, follow the manufacturer's recommendation as far as oil and filter changes and every one I have ever seen says something like "3 months or 3000 miles whichever comes first."  In your case, the "months" are coming first and so your car is due for an oil change.

You don't have to do it but should do it in order to maximize its life.

Comment: Engines have been designed around a 100,000 mile change but there are double filters etc to compensate....

Comment: In the uk/europe its more common for cars to require pil/filter changes every 10,000 km to 20,000km

Comment: My comment about "3 months or 3000 miles" was merely an example.  Let's say "N months or M miles (K kilometers)" instead.  Ok? Whatever the interval or distance it will be listed in the Owners Manual.